# Raspberry PI GPIO mutli-threading Kegerator

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I wanted to consult with minds that were more familiar with Python.

The back story is I have a Kegerator with multiple taps (always a difficult decision when you want a drink). I have several flow sensors wired into it, and I am using the RPI for logging the data to my server.

At the moment the code I am using works if only 1 flow sensor is being used. However if multiple beers (flow sensor ticks) it combines the results.

Now I believe I need multiple classes defined for each kegerator, and create functions for each keg, but I wanted to confirm that with you guys.

http://pythonfiddle.com/flowmeter-app

http://pythonfiddle.com/flowmeter-class

Any help would be appreciated. If you are in the Boston area, there could be a beer in it for you.

Comment: you don't need separate classes, but separate instances of the same class likely...

Comment: First off, awesome use of the RPI+Python!  When you say "if multiple beers (flow sensor ticks) it combines the results", do you mean that it aggregates counts if multiple taps are open at once, or that it always just sums up your tap counts to one singular counter?

Comment: Thank you kindly.. Yes it sees which ever sensor has flow going through it. Any subsequent flowmeters I start using while that is being use get added to the total of that one.

Basically what you said, it sums up total counts into one counter.